# Regex contains only numbers with optional ||/&& and number

Tags: javascript, regex, boolean

examples where the regex should return true: `1&&2`, `1||2`, `1&&2||3`, `1`
examples where the regex should return false: `1||`, `1&&`, `&&2`

My regex is:

```
[0-9]+([\\|\\|\\&&][0-9])*
```

but it returns true if the input is `1&&&2`.
Where is my mistake?

Comment: Replace `[\|\|\&&]` with `(?:\|\||&&)` and use anchors to match the whole string

Comment: Yet another regexp newbie who thinks `[]` is for grouping. Why is this such a common mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `[\|\|\&&]` matches a single `|` or `&` char, not `||` or `&&` sequences of chars. Also, the `[0-9]` without a quantifier matches only one digit. Without anchors, you may match a string partially inside a longer string.

You may use

```
^[0-9]+(?:(?:\|\||&&)[0-9]+)*$
```

Actually, to match anywhere inside a string, keep on using the pattern without anchors:

```
[0-9]+(?:(?:\|\||&&)[0-9]+)*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ivAzFe/2/)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:(?:\|\||&&)[0-9])*` - 0 or more repetitions of

  - `(?:\|\||&&)` - `||` or `&&` sequence of characters
  - `[0-9]+`  - 1+ digits
- `$` - end of string.

JS demo:

```js
const reg = /^[0-9]+(?:(?:\|\||&&)[0-9]+)*$/;
console.log( reg.test('1||2') ); // => true
```

Comment: It was really helpful!Thank you!

Comment: let reg = RegExp('^[0-9]+(?:(?:\|\||&&)[0-9]+)*$'); console.log(reg.test('1||2')); return false, where is my mistake?

Comment: @User546 `let reg = /^[0-9]+(?:(?:\|\||&&)[0-9]+)*$/`

Comment: How can I adapt this to Java? Pattern.matches("/^[0-9]+(?:(?:\|\||&&)[0-9]+)*$/", "1||2") returns invalid escape sequence

Comment: @User546 `Pattern.compile("[0-9]+(?:(?:\\|\\||&&)[0-9]+)*").matcher("1||2").matches()`